# Excel table fill every third row

Tags: excel, fill, autofill

I need help with issue I'm having.

I got 2 sheets, 1st sheet is the table I need to fill and 2nd one is the data.
In the data part I have column A with employee number and B with names.

On the first sheet I have table that I need to fill but table is like this:

- Blank row
- Number column + Name column
- Blank row

So when I just drag data to auto fill every third row formula skips employees and I only get every third name.

What can I do to fill every third row from 2nd sheet but without skipping names?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of round about way that I have done it.  On datasheet insert column a and put in values A1(1)A2(3)A3(5), Fill down this pattern this is to use as an index for filling the columns on your other sheet.  On the sheet you are filling, insert a new column a and add 1,2,3 and fill down.

I used this vlookup:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,datasheet!A:C,2,FALSE),"")
```

I copy this to column b and fill both of these columns down.  Now you have your values.  You will have to do a copy and paste values to get rid of the formulas once the info is in there. Select all, copy. and Ctrl+Alt+V and select values to do the paste special.

Hope this helps.